# Sum all values from a textview from a list with custom layout

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listadapter

I have a list with a custom layout that is loaded from a sqlite db. One of the items from the custom layout is an integer. I want to sum all those values.

Here is my code:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    ItemsCursorAdapter adapter = new ItemsCursorAdapter(
            this, R.layout.row_layout, cursor, 0 );

    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
    TextView amount = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.valueText);

    String amountSt = amount.getText().toString();

    int amountInt = Integer.getInteger(amountSt);
```

Comment: if you're using db, why don't you use sql query to sum?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by saying "One of the items from the custom layout is an integer." ?

Comment: @KingfisherPhuoc that's it a very simple way, I was make it very confuse